# Simple lookup to insert values in an R data frame

Tags: r, lookup-tables

This is a seemingly simple R question, but I don't see an exact answer here.  I have a data frame (alldata) that looks like this:

```
Case     zip     market
1        44485   NA
2        44488   NA
3        43210   NA
```

There are over 3.5 million records.

Then, I have a second data frame, 'zipcodes'.

```
market    zip
1         44485
1         44486
1         44488
...       ... (100 zips in market 1)
2         43210
2         43211
...       ... (100 zips in market 2, etc.)
```

I want to find the correct value for alldata$market for each case based on alldata$zip matching the appropriate value in the zipcode data frame.  I'm just looking for the right syntax, and assistance is much appreciated, as usual.

Comment: you are looking for `merge`.   search SO for `[r] merge` and you will find it

Comment: @Ricardo Saporta on 3.5 `merge` may be a bit slow.

Comment: @TylerRinker, I use `merge.data.table` on 400 Million rows often, and its quite fast.  Good call on using `qdap` though

Comment: Oh wow never worked with data that large.  Thanks for the experience informed response.

Answer (score 14):

Since you don't care about the `market` column in `alldata`, you can first strip it off using and merge the columns in `alldata` and `zipcodes` based on the `zip` column using `merge`:

```
merge(alldata[, c("Case", "zip")], zipcodes, by="zip")
```

The `by` parameter specifies the key criteria, so if you have a compound key, you could do something like `by=c("zip", "otherfield")`.

Comment: Won't this introduce NAs for zip codes that are not in alldata?

Comment: @Rodrigo By default, you'll get only rows with matches in both data frames. That can be controlled with the `all`, `all.x`, and `all.y` options

Answer (score 9):

Another option that worked for me and  is very simple:

```
alldata$market<-with(zipcodes, market[match(alldata$zip, zip)])
```

Comment: So simple yet so great!

Comment: It would be great if you could explain what's going on there.

Comment: From R docs: "`match` returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second". So basically `match` returns a vector of right indices to access zipcodes$market to get the right market values for alldata$market.

Answer (score 4):

With such a large data set you may want the speed of an environment lookup.  You can use the `lookup` function from the [qdapTools package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qdapTools/index.html) as follows:

```
library(qdapTools)
alldata$market <- lookup(alldata$zip, zipcodes[, 2:1])
```

Or

```
alldata$zip %l% zipcodes[, 2:1]
```

Comment: Tyler, I tested this on a bit bigger data and the step `lookup(.)` proved time consuming (I stopped it after a while). I've it as a [**gist**](https://gist.github.com/arunsrinivasan/ee2d9ef43bdc02c32958). Am I doing it right? With a quick debug, the time consuming portion seems to be `sapply(.)` inside `recoder` function.

Comment: @Arun Thanks for the gist.  I added some improvements in the [dev version](https://github.com/trinker/qdapTools) based on your findings that makes significant speed boosts.

Comment: Just out of curiosity did you bench `data.table` to see how it compares.  I have read `data.table` has made some nice improvements in lookups including character lookups.

Comment: I've edited the gist with two ways. 1) A join (although it is really not needed here) and 2) using `match` and `:=`, would be nicer to benchmark on huge data though. HTH.

Comment: Yes, quite a few welcoming changes from 1.9.0+. This should be convincing: `require(data.table); set.seed(1L); x = sample(paste0("V", 1:1e6)); system.time(ans1 <- data.table:::forderv(x)); system.time(ans2 <- order(x)); identical(ans1, ans2)`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the `dplyr` way of doing it:

```
library(tidyverse)
alldata %>%
  select(-market) %>%
  left_join(zipcodes, by="zip")
```

which, on my machine, is roughly the same performance as `lookup`.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `match` is a bit clumsy.  You might find the `lookup` package easier to use.

```
alldata <- data.frame(Case=1:3, zip=c(44485,44488,43210), market=c(NA,NA,NA))
zipcodes <- data.frame(market=c(1,1,1,2,2), zip=c(44485,44486,44488,43210,43211))
alldata$market <- lookup(alldata$zip, zipcodes$zip, zipcodes$market)
alldata
##   Case   zip market
## 1    1 44485      1
## 2    2 44488      1
## 3    3 43210      2
```