# How to find certain value similar to vlookup in excel? And how to create dataframe with for loop?

Tags: excel, loops, for-loop, vlookup

I have two dataframes both have 2 columns (2 variables).

I was thinking that I could use something similar to vlookup in excel?
And maybe I could create a new dataset using for loop and put the quotients in this dataset I don't know how exactly I could do that.

(I ALSO NEED TO PUT THE VALUES IN A DATASET so the suggested post does not answer my question completely)

example:

```
dataframe1
number amount
 1  2
 2  3
 3  4


dataframe2
number amount
 1  5
 2  6
 4  2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple lookup to insert values in an R data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17844143/simple-lookup-to-insert-values-in-an-r-data-frame)

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. It's more difficult to answer abstractly.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you imported Dataframe1 as `Dataframe1`, and Dataframe2 as `Dataframe2`, and both are `data.frame`.

```
library(tidyverse)
Dataframe1 %>%
  inner_join(Dataframe2 %>% rename(Amount2 = Amount),
             by="id") -> Dataframe
```

At this point you can perform your operation

```
library(tidyverse)
Dataframe %>%
  mutate(result = Amount/Amount2) -> Dataframe
```

and check if the column `result` is what you were looking for.

To find the highest ratio:

```
Dataframe$result %>% max(na.rm = T)
```

But there are many other ways to record this value; this is the most straightforward.